# Bounded inverse theorem when the domain is not complete

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

The [bounded inverse theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_inverse_theorem) states that a bijective bounded linear operator $T$ from a Banach space $X$ to a Banach space $Y$ has a bounded linear inverse $T^{-1}$.
I want to find a constructive counterexample to this when the domain $X$ is not complete but all other conditions are satisfied.
In particular, I want a non-complete normed linear space $X$, a Banach space $Y$, and a bijective bounded linear opeartor $T:X\to Y$ such that $T^{-1}$ is not bounded.

I found a counterexample [when the codomain $Y$ is not complete](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1824196/inverse-operator-theorem-counter-example) or [when the operator is not bijective](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3736138/counterexample-to-inverse-operator-theorem),
but I want to maintain that $Y$ is complete and $T$ is bijective. I think there are hints in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3066485/open-mapping-theorem-fails-when-space-is-not-complete) or [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2145982/converse-of-bounded-inverse-theorem), but in either, I could not come up with a specific constructive choice of $g$ or $\varphi$ that makes only $X$ non-complete but maintains all other conditions. (For the latter post, the constructive map $\varphi$ is not defined for non-basis elements of $X$.)

Comment: If you have such a map the inverse will be an unbounded operator with domain a Banach space. I think such a thing is non-constructive, ie there is some kind of a statement along the lines of "there exist models of set theory without choice in which every linear operator defined on a Banach space into a normed space is continuous" (I don't know if this language is correct). At any rate if you google "unbounded operator between Banach spaces" you may find relevant statements (note that you can include $X$ into its completion, so $A^{-1}$ can be assumed to have codomain Banach).

Comment: By constructive, I don't mean not using the axiom of choice. It is ok to use the axiom of choice as long as I see what it is. I just don't want "let this be an arbitrary unbounded operator" construction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X$ be a VS with a Hamel basis with the cardinality of the continuum, let $\{ e_r\mid r\in\Bbb (0,1)\}$ be such a basis and give $X$ the norm
$$\left\|\sum_{r} x_r \ e_r\right\|_X:=\sum_r|x_r|$$
(remember that only finitely many terms in that sum are not zero). Now let $Y$ be an infinite dimensional Banach space of cardinality $|\Bbb R|$, like $\ell^1(\Bbb N)$. Then any Hamel basis of $Y$ has cardinality $|\Bbb R|$, suppose $\{ b_r \mid r\in(0,1)\}$ is such a basis and wlog assume $\|b_r\|_Y=1$, else replace $b_r$ by $b_r/\|b_r\|$.

Now the map
$$B:X\to Y, \qquad \sum_r x_r\ e_r\mapsto \sum_r r\,x_r \ b_r$$
is continuous because
$$\|B(\sum_r x_r \ e_r)\|_Y ≤\sum_r r |x_r| \ \|b_r\|≤ \sum_r |x_r| = \left\|\sum_r x_r \ e_r\right\|_X,$$
ie it is a contraction. Further it is a linear bijection by construction. However the inverse cannot be bounded simply because $\|B^{-1}( b_r/\|b_r\|) \| = \frac1r$ with $r$ ranging over $(0,1)$, hence the image of the unit ball under $B^{-1}$ is unbounded.

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful! How can I verify that $X$ is not complete?

Comment: If $X$ were complete then the open mapping theorem would imply that $B$ is an isomorphism, in particular that its inverse is bounded. If you want to explicitly find a non-converging Cauchy sequence consider $(\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1k x_k\, e_{1/k})_{n\in \Bbb N}$.